# Why is my random array sorting in 0.001 seconds?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I'm making a program that compares the times of 4 different types of sorts. Each sort uses a sorted array, a reverse sorted array, and a randomly filled array. The times for the sorted and reverse sorted look correct, but the randomly filled always returns <0.01, no matter the input size. My main looks like this:

```
        System.out.println("---------LEFT PIVOT----------\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int[][] a = makearrays((int) (_SIZE * Math.pow(2, i)));
            System.out.println("SIZE: " + _SIZE * Math.pow(2, i));
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Sort.quicksort(a[k], 0, a[k].length - 1);
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                long time = end - start;
                System.out.println("Time for " + types[k] + ": " + (time / 1000.0) + " seconds.");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
```

Where a[0] is the sorted, a[1] is the reverse sorted, and a[2] is the random sorted. Here's a sample of the output:

```
Time for SORTED ARRAY: 1.212 seconds.

Time for REVERSE SORTED ARRAY: 5.226 seconds.

Time for RANDOM ARRAY: 0.008 seconds.
```

On another run, it outputs this:

```
Time for SORTED ARRAY: 1.19 seconds.

Time for REVERSE SORTED ARRAY: 4.053 seconds.

Time for RANDOM ARRAY: 0.009 seconds.
```

I printed the arrays before and after each sort, and can confirm the random array is completely random before the sort, and sorted after. Does anyone have any idea why it would be printing such a small time? Thanks.

Edit:
In that example, I used the following:

```
        int _SIZE = 100000;
```

Here's how the arrays are generated:

```
    public static int[][] makearrays(int size) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[][] a = new int[3][size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            a[0][i] = i;
            a[1][i] = size - i - 1;
            a[2][i] = r.nextInt(size);
        }
        return a;
    }
```

And this is what my quicksort looks like:

```
public static void quicksort(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            int s = partition(arr, l, r);
            quicksort(arr, l, s-1);
            quicksort(arr, s+1, r);
        } 
    }

    public static int partition(int[] arr, int l, int r) {
        int p=arr[l],i=l+1;

        for (int j =l+1;j<=r;j++) {
            if (arr[j]<p) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
                i++;
            }
        }
        
        int temp = arr[l];
        arr[l] = arr[i-1];
        arr[i-1] = temp;
        return i-1;
    }
```

Comment: You'll want t show a [mcve] here.

Comment: Well, how long is the "random array", and how is it generated?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I've added another output, and the rest of the code, thanks

Comment: @kaya3 At first it's whatever "_SIZE" is, and in the example it is 100000. So it should definitely not be that short. Additionally, the array sizes increase by a factor of 2^i, so n, 2n, 4, and 8n. And all of those look identical to the 0.009s. I've added the array generation code.

Comment: Well, the two cases you're comparing it against are the worst cases for your version of quicksort, since you consistently choose the pivot as the first element from the sub-array, so it will degrade to O(n^2) time.

Comment: @kaya3 My bad. I forgot to include that it also does this for the central pivot, median of 3, and random pivot.

Comment: Well, nobody can suggest what might be causing the issue with those implementations since you didn't post any code for them. This is why you need to provide a [mcve].